# How to modify JSON Object retrived from MongoDB?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, angular

So I am making a rest call to get this JSON Object:

```
{  
    "_id":"57a0811276e75ba815d248b0",
    "gName":"demo-layout",
    "gType":"Content",
    "wsId":"57a036c376e75ba815d248ac",
    "desc":"Demo-Layout for rapidpage",
    "createdDate":"2016-08-02T11:16:34.223Z",
    "__v":0
}
```

Now I want to add an array to this object ,something like this:

```
{  
    "_id":"57a0811276e75ba815d248b0",
    "gName":"demo-layout",
    "gType":"Content",
    "wsId":"57a036c376e75ba815d248ac",
    "desc":"Demo-Layout for rapidpage",
    "createdDate":"2016-08-02T11:16:34.223Z",
    "blocks":[], //should be added at runtime 
    "__v":0
}
```

So I tried following:

```
dbPage:any={};
ngOnInit(){
    let pageId:string="57a0811276e75ba815d248b0";
    this._pagesService.getPageById(pageId).subscribe((Page)=>{
        this.dbPage=rapidPage;
        console.log(this.dbPage); //this prints the object as shown above     
    });
    this.dbPage.blocks=[];
    this.dbPage.blocks.push(block1);
}
```

But its not modifying the current object,instead its creating new Object as :

```
{blocks: Array[]}
```

any inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not assigning it in the `subscribe` call. Due to the async nature of HTTP requests in JavaScript, the code below the `subscribe` call will be executed before the callback inside the `subscribe` call.

You can easily fix this by moving the code inside the callback:

```ts
dbPage: any = {};
ngOnInit(){
    let pageId: string = "57a0811276e75ba815d248b0";
    this._pagesService.getPageById(pageId).subscribe((rapidPage) => {
        this.dbPage = rapidPage;
        console.log(this.dbPage); //this prints the object as shown above   

        this.dbPage.blocks = [];
        this.dbPage.blocks.push(block1);
    });
}
```